# Narrowing subclasses of pointer member in derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I have a class hierarchy that is broken in two - high level objects, and low-level and swappable connection interfaces. The connection objects form a class hierarchy, where each adds more features to the connection. Similarly, the high-level class hierarchy needs progressively better connections.

The connection objects look like the following:

```
class BaseConnection {
    virtual void a() = 0;
};
class BetterConnection : public BaseConnection {
    virtual void b() = 0;
}
class BestConnection : public BetterConnection {
    virtual void c() = 0;
}
```

Here's my attempt at writing the high level objects

```
struct Base {
protected:
    // This type is correct for `Base`, but `Better` and `Best` need access to a more derived type.
    unique_ptr<BaseConnection> const m_conn;
public:
    Base(unique_ptr<BaseConnection> conn) : m_conn(std::move(conn));
    void do_a_twice() {
        auto& conn = *m_conn;
        conn.a(); conn.a();
    }
};
struct Better : public Base {
    Better(unique_ptr<BetterConnection> conn) : Base(std::move(conn));
    void do_b_twice() {
        auto& conn = dynamic_cast<BetterConnection&>(*m_conn);
        conn.b(); conn.b();
    }
};
struct Best : public Better {
    unique_ptr<BetterConnection> conn;
    Better(unique_ptr<BetterConnection> conn) : Better(std::move(conn));
    void do_c_twice() {
        auto& conn = dynamic_cast<BestConnection&>(*m_conn);
        conn.b(); conn.b();
    }
};
```

So, my questions:

1. Is there a way to achieve this without `dynamic_cast`?
2. Am I right in thinking this incurs a runtime overhead of using runtime-type-information?
3. Is it safe to use `reinterpret_cast` here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the abstractions around your `Connection` types are making things more difficult (whereas abstraction is supposed to *simplify* things).

Why do the `Connection` types have different members? If the derived `Connection` classes instead overrode the `BaseConnection`, you can rely on virtual function dispatch to do the right thing at runtime. For example

```
struct BaseConnection {                             
    virtual void connect() {                        
        cout << "BaseConnection::connect" << endl;  
    }                                               
};                                                  

struct BetterConnection : public BaseConnection {   
    void connect() override {                       
        cout << "BetterConnection::connect" << endl;
    }                                               
};                                                  

struct BestConnection : public BetterConnection {   
    void connect() override {                       
        cout << "BestConnection::connect" << endl;  
    }                                               
};                                                  

class X {                                           
public:                                             
    X(std::unique_ptr<BaseConnection> connection)   
        : connection_(std::move(connection))        
    {                                               
        connection_->connect();                     
    }                                               

private:                                            
    std::unique_ptr<BaseConnection> connection_;    
};                                                  

int main() {                                        
    X(std::make_unique<BaseConnection>());          
    X(std::make_unique<BetterConnection>());        
    X(std::make_unique<BestConnection>());          
}
```

If the `Connection` types have different methods because they truly are performing different actions, then it begs the question if inheritance was the right abstraction to use.

Perhaps you could add a virtual method that you override to 'do the right thing' for each derived `Connection`. Then the higher-level class only needs to call this one method, and it can be done without casting.

In general, if you find yourself having to use `dynamic_cast` to perform type inspection at runtime, it probably means the interfaces were not designed for polymorphism in mind. I would rethink the interfaces between your objects and try to see if there is a way to get what you want without having to upcast.

---

### Edit: Using type traits

Based on your comments, it seems like you may require more customization of your higher-level objects than my original answer provided. In essence, I think what you're trying to do is case on what underlying `Connection` type you're managing, and provide different implementations of higher level functions.

A common way to do this (and how the STL does this) is via operator overloading with type traits. To illustrate, begin with a few types that describe *traits* of the underlying connection objects.

```
struct base_connection_tag {};                               
struct better_connection_tag : public base_connection_tag {};
struct best_connection_tag : public better_connection_tag {};
```

And then we can add them to the `Connection` classes.

```
struct BaseConnection {                               
    virtual void a() {                                
        cout << "BaseConnection::a()" << endl;        
    }                                                 

    using connection_category = base_connection_tag;  
};                                                    

struct BetterConnection : public BaseConnection {     
    virtual void b() {                                
        cout << "BetterConnection::b()" << endl;      
    }                                                 

    using connection_category = better_connection_tag;
};                                                    

struct BestConnection : public BetterConnection {     
    virtual void c() {                                
        cout << "BestConnection::c" << endl;          
    }                                                 

    using connection_category = best_connection_tag;  
};
```

By convention, `connection_traits` echos the `Connection` class's nested typedef

```
template <typename ConnectionT>                                           
struct connection_traits {                                                
    using connection_category = typename ConnectionT::connection_category;
};
```

Finally, we can use operator overloading to decide which implementation to call in some higher level class (or classes) using a pattern like this:

```
template <typename T>                                                 
class Dispatch                                                        
{                                                                     
public:                                                               
    Dispatch(std::unique_ptr<T> connection)                           
        : connection_(std::move(connection))                          
    {}                                                                

    void operator()() {                                               
        connect(typename connection_traits<T>::connection_category());
    }                                                                 

private:                                                              

    void connect(base_connection_tag) {                               
        connection_->a();                                             
    }                                                                 

    void connect(better_connection_tag) {                             
        connection_->b();                                             
    }                                                                 

    void connect(best_connection_tag) {                               
        connection_->c();                                             
    }                                                                 

    std::unique_ptr<T> connection_;                                   
};
```

When the `()` operator is called, the `Dispatch` class calls one of the `connect` methods using the `connection_traits` of the underlying `Connection`.

Since all the types are known at compile time, the `Dispatch` class knows which base method to call during compilation. No `dynamic_cast` is needed to determine which type is held.

Although I only used a single template class to implement higher order functionality, you could feasibly use multiple non-template classes to do the same thing, using `connection_traits` and function argument overloading in each to enable/disable functionality.

Comment: _"Why do the Connection types have different members?"_ - because each connection type supports more options. For instance, `Base` might support only a heartbeat, `Better` beat + read operations, and `Best` beat + read + write operations

Comment: And I meant `*Connection` for all those classnames above

Comment: That makes sense. Is it possible to create a consistent interface across all of them? If so, polymorphism solves the problem nicely, and you only need one higher level class. Otherwise, I still don't see what polymorphism in the higher level classes buys you—you'd have to customize them so much, a dedicated, non-polymorphic class for each `Connection` would be simpler.

Comment: The higher level classes are polymorphic to share code - I want to be able to call `Best::do_a_twice()` without writing `do_a_twice()` again. Obviously these methods are contrived, but the basic principle is the `{X}Connection` objects provide a set of building blocks, and the `{X}` classes build compound operations out of them. I want to represent the fact that a superset of building blocks produces a superset of compound operations.

Comment: @Eric please note that I've edited my answer to include an example using what are called 'type traits'. Type traits allow for what is essentially compile-time `if...else` conditionals on types using templates and _function overloading_. Your set of higher-level classes can therefore use the type traits of the `Connection` objects to do different things for each type.